# Como ativar apenas a próxima div?

Tags: html, jquery

Na minha página eu tenho vários elementos que preferi esconder para não deixar o site muito grande, mas ao clicar em mostrar um, ele expande todos da página. Como eu faço para ele selecionar apenas o próximo elemento?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".flip").click(function(){
            $(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
        });
    });
```

Assim ta o JQuery e no código está assim:

```
    <div class="flip"><b><u>Expandir/Esconder</u></b></div>
    <div class="panel">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cara use o método `.next()` do jQuery junto com o seleto `this`, o `this` vai pegar apenas o elemento que vc clicou, e o `next()` vai selecionar o próximo elemento com a classe que vc definir

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".flip").click(function() {
    $(this).next(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<div class="flip"><b><u>Expandir/Esconder</u></b></div>
<div class="panel">
  111
</div>
<div class="flip"><b><u>Expandir/Esconder</u></b></div>
<div class="panel">
  222
</div>
```

Aqui tem a documentação oficial do `.next()` https://api.jquery.com/next/

Answer (score 2):

Use `$(this).next('.panel')` no lugar de `$(".panel")`. Isso fará que seja acessado o próximo *panel* em relação ao elemento clicado, em vez de selecionar todos

Comment: Rapaz esse pontinhos das peguntas deram um UP ai hein! 

Comment: Tá falando da reputação? Também achei estranho, lembrava de ter 6k, um belo dia olho e tem 2k a mais. Deve ter dado um bug na SE, tava até olhando minha aba de reputação ontem pra ver da onde tinha saído isso

Comment: As resposta até semana passada valiam 5pts, agora passou para 10pts, ai foi retroativo, deram +5 para as perguntas antigas tb :D, levei 3.5k nessa rss

Comment: @hugocsl tô totalmente desatualizado shusauhusahuhsa

Answer (score 0):

Outra forma é pegando o índice da classe `.flip` clicada e aplicar ao mesmo índice da classe `.panel`.

A vantagem desta forma sobre o `.next()` é que o elemento `.panel` não precisa ser irmão do elemento `.flip`. O `.next()` só funciona com elementos irmãos e que estejam após o elemento selecionado.

Por exemplo, se tiver a estrutura abaixo, o `.next()` já não vai funcionar:

```
<div class="flip"><b><u>Expandir/Esconder</u></b></div>
<div>
   <div class="panel">painel 1</div>
</div>
```

Note acima que a `div.panel` não é irmã da `div.flip`.

Pegando o índice, como falei, funciona em qualquer caso, pois cada índice da classe `.flip` é "casada" com cada índice da classe `.panel`.

Basta fazer isso:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".flip").click(function(){
      var idx = $(".flip").index(this); // pega o índice
      $(".panel").eq(idx).slideToggle("slow");
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flip"><b><u>Expandir/Esconder</u></b></div>
<div class="panel">painel 1</div>

<div class="flip"><b><u>Expandir/Esconder</u></b></div>
<div class="panel">painel 2</div>
```

O `.index()` me retorna o índice do `.flip` clicado e uso `.eq()` para pegar o mesmo índice da classe `.panel`. Muito simples!